# Finding equation of tangent line when $f '(x) = 1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the equation:
$$f(x) = x^4 + 2x^2$$

Find the equation of the tangent line when $f '(x) = 1$.

I know to set $f '(x)$ to $1$, but it is the work after that that is giving me trouble.

Comment: The solution for $x$ is quite messy. Could you recheck the question to make sure it's reproduced accurately? For example the question is much easier if it were 'find the equation of the tangent line at $x=1$.'

Comment: Yes, I rechecked it several times before I posted the question here.  It is possible that my teacher just gave a typo, but I am unwilling to rely on that possibility until I'm certain that this can't be solved neatly.